# Accessing a view's DOM elements in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many views that have `<%= f.text_field :column %>` where they should have `<%= f.number_field :column %>` as they are integers in the schema.

Is it possible to write a rake task to figure out which columns are integers in the schema but text fields in the views?

Comment: How many views are we talking? Would it be simpler to do a "find" in your text editor and selectively change the files?

Comment: Hundreds of files. Thousands of columns. Text editor find is not going to cut it.

Comment: Understood. Off the top of my head, you might be able to directly leverage something like the [Deface gem](https://github.com/spree/deface).